# Windows 10 ICMPv6 Echo Request/Reply not working

Tags: networking, windows-10, ipv6

I have a strange problem that even though my firewall is completely disabled I can't ping my default IPv6 gateway.

When I ping it from a Linux box it is working as expected but under Windows 10 something is blocking the `Echo Reply` from the gateway. I did a packet capture on the gateway and have seen the `Echo Request` arriving and also the `Echo Reply` leaving.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
I also did a packet capture on the Windows machine verifying that the `Echo Reply` isn't arriving. The default gateway address is a link-local address `fe80::215:5dff:fe02:670d`. Internet connection via IPv6 works from Linux and Windows. Also ICMPv6 `Router Advertisement` and `Neighbour Solicitation` are being received.

Comment: This sounds pretty tricky.  It sounds like you've done a great job summarizing the most critical details.  I'd be very interested in knowing what the IPv6 addresses are.  (Although, if they don't start with fd, you may want to obfuscate the first/common parts.)  Have you tried sniffing network traffic on Windows machine?  I've had similar issues caused by routing challenges; the routing table on the gateway may provide answers.  (When you packet captured, did you only capture on the interface that the packet should have gone out, or all outgoing traffic?)

Comment: @TOOGAM I did a packet capture on the Windows machine and on the gateway/router. Router sends Echo reply but the capture on Windows doesn't show. The used gateway address is a link-local IPv6 address (fe80::215:5dff:fe02:670d) which is pingable from a linux machine without problems. IPv6 connection to the Internet is working from Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved itself without any intervention. I suspect some strange caching issues.